# Focus text input after toggling visibility (using AngularJS directives)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need a `<div>` with a text `<input>` to be toggled visible and then focus on the text element.

Pressing a button sets two conditions to true, one to show the parent element, and another to focus the input element.

I'm using two custom directives:

- The **ng-visible** directive toggles the visibility property (visible / hidden) when evaluated truthful.
- The **ng-focus** directive focuses the element when evaluated truthful.

---

The problem I ran into is my directive tries to focus the element too soon (before the block has had enough time to display as visibility: visible) and thus the focusing fails. Quick test reveals if a 1 second long $timeout delay is added, it works fine.

How can I ensure the focus directive waits until its visible before trying to focus the element?

---

*Minor note*: I am aware of ng-show / ng-hide (which works in my testing), but I need to use the CSS visibility property here instead.

---

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="showMe = true; focusMe = true;"></button>

<div ng-visible="showMe">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="focusMe"/>
</div>
```

**Visibility Directive**

```
app.directive('ngVisible', function($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        multiElement: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngVisible, function(value) {
                if( value === true ) {
                    $animate.removeClass(element, 'invisible', function() {
                            scope.$apply();
                    });
                } else {
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'invisible', function() {
                    scope.$apply();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Focus Directive**

```
app.directive('ngFocus', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var model = $parse(attr.ngFocus);

            scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
                if(value === true) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element[0].focus(); 
                    });
                }
            });

            // Set attr value to false on blur event so it can be refocused
            element.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Post a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/